# Access Query with Count and Distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to develop a simple query in which I'm trying to do Count of distinct values from a field, i have tried to use DISTINCT in query which throws error.

Please guide me to fix this code, thanks.

```
SELECT TSData.[Upd Bay], Sum(TSData.RT) AS RT, Sum(TSData.OT) AS OT, Count(DISTINCT TSData.[EMP No]) AS EmpCount
FROM TSData
WHERE (((TSData.[TS Date])=Nz([Forms]![TSDataDeptSummary]![CmbTSDate],Date()-1)))
GROUP BY TSData.[Upd Bay];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSJIf.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you code is throwing an error please include the full error message in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, error snap attached.

Comment: Can't use DISTINCT like that. Correct syntax would be `SELECT DISTINCT` but if I remember correctly, cannot use DISTINCT and GROUP BY in same query. Edit question to show data and desired output as text tables. BTW, error msg should be text, not image.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT is not supported by MsAccess

Answer (score 0):

You can separately query those parts and combine as subqueries:

```
select A.[Upd Bay], A.[TS Date],  DCnt.EmpCnt
from 
    (
        SELECT A.[Upd Bay], A.[TS Date]
        FROM TSData A
        WHERE A.[Ts Date]=Nz([Forms]![TSDataDeptSummary]![CmbTSDate],Date()-1)
        group by  A.[Upd Bay], A.[TS Date]
    ) A

    inner join
    (
        select [Upd Bay], count([Emp No]) as EmpCnt
        from (
                select distinct  B.[Upd Bay],  B.[Emp No] 
                from TSData B 
                where B.[Ts Date]=Nz([Forms]![TSDataDeptSummary]![CmbTSDate],Date()-1)
            ) as Dnt
        group by [Upd Bay]
    ) as DCnt
    on A.[Upd Bay]=DCnt.[Upd Bay]
```

Comment: Maybe you can accept as answer?